# Send email Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, smtp, indy, delphi-xe5

i'm trying to send email from Delphi **XE5** (android) with Indy components:

In form i have a `TIdSMTP` and a `TIDMessage`.

When the form is created:

```
testform:=Ttestform.create(self);
testform.show;
```

the **application halt's** and i dont know what is wrong... i supose Indy components aren't compatible in Android...

```
  IdSMTP1.Heloname:='test';
  IdSMTP1.Host:='smtp.gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Username:='umail@gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Port:=465;
  IdSMTP1.Password:='pass';

  if IdSMTP1.Connected=True then IdSMTP1.Disconnect;

  IdMessage1.clear;
  IdMessage1.From.Text :='Testing';
  IdMessage1.BccList.EMailAddresses :='umail@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Priority := mpHigh;
  IdMessage1.Sender.Text:='Umail';
  IdMessage1.Subject := 'Subject';
  IdMessage1.Body.Add('test');
  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  Try
    IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
  except
  End;
```

Anyone use this?!

The Form Dont SHOW application is halted...
Please see the full source here http://pastebin.com/iGtJrHHs

Comment: You're missing trailing quote on `IdMessage1.BccList.EMailAddresses :='umail@gmail.com;;` line.

Comment: While I can't get IdSMTP to do anything but make my app unresponsive (1st gen Nexus 7) when I click my "Send mail" button. The form appears just fine at app startup.  Perhaps you can start with a blank application and add one component at a time and starting again.

Comment: Then you need to debug your app. First confirm whether TIdSMTP is even at fault, don't just assume it is. If it is at fault (which I doubt), you can then trace into its source code to find the actual hang.  Or, you could simply redesign your code to remove the TIdSMTP from the TForm, and move it into a worker thread instead (which you should do anyway since you should never block the main thread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a direct answer to the issue with Indy, but if you considered switching tack and using the in-built email creation options on Android, you could use code like this:

```
uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
...
procedure CreateEmail(const Recipient, Subject, Content: string);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  Recipients: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  Recipients := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  Recipients.Items[0] := StringToJString(Recipient);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, Recipients);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString(Content));
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('plain/text'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(TJIntent.JavaClass.createChooser(Intent,
    StrToJCharSequence('Which email app?')));
end;
```

I'll leave it to someone else to proffer a solution to the Indy trouble.

Comment: i accept this solution to manage problem, because Indy IdSMTP isn't compatible with android.

Comment: Yes, TIdSMTP is compatible with Android.  Other people have had success using it. You are the first person I have seen report a problem using it.

Comment: I have the same problem. @Remy maybe you publish your solution? I create TIdMessage in code and when I change it's properties then app hangs (does not response on any click). At the moment I will take blong's solution.

Comment: @mad: merely setting a property value cannot cause a hang. Something else is going on.  Which EXACT line of code hangs?

Answer (score 1):

user1147833;

you should do an authenticate operation after connect to server.

Just swicth to your code ;

```
IdSMTP1.Connect;
IdSMTP1.Authenticate;
  Try
    IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
  except
  End;
```

Comment: im sending a lotf of emailf with indy and if you wish i can share the detailed code. But it is developed for my process and not compatible with Android. 

Butseems like your app is halted coz it is not auhenticated and it cannot continue this way. 

I think your error in code is simple and just add one line to your code. Please feel free to send here "error code" for us, to understan what is going on.

Comment: dont work, thanks. The form halt's before show... so isn't Autentication failure, but a problem in IdSMTP (i think)

Comment: @user1147833, if you're doing the send in the create, then this still makes sense.

Comment: no, i dont send in show obviously... is in a button and the form doesn't show.

Comment: TIdSMTP.Send() calls TIdSMTP.Authenticate() internally, so there is no need to call it explicitly.

Comment: i cant because the form dont show... i think is a component "constructor" because when i call formsender:=Tformsender.create(self); formsender.show; application dont response. simply halt's

Comment: There is nothing in `TIdSMTP` (or any other Indy component) that should be preventing the Form from showing, unless you are performing a blocking socket operation inside the Form's `OnShow` event.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up a number of items, none of which will help if your form isn't actually showing.
The below successfully sent a message from a 1st gen Nexus 7 using a SMTP server requiring authentication and operating on Port 25.

If you are really connecting to port 465 on Google's servers you have to be using encryption which this code does not address.

The simple assignments of IdMessage1.From.Text := 'blah blah'; Were not working so you'll see I substituted in IdMessage1.From.Address and the similar properties for the other IdMessage1 properties.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase, IdSMTP, IdMessage,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit;

type
  Ttestform = class(TForm)
    IdSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
    IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
    btnMessageSend: TButton;
    edtUsername: TEdit;
    edtPassword: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    edtFrom: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    edtTo: TEdit;
    Label4: TLabel;
    edtServer: TEdit;
    Label5: TLabel;
    edtPort: TEdit;
    Label6: TLabel;
    procedure btnMessageSendClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  testform: Ttestform;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure Ttestform.btnMessageSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  intPort: Integer;
begin
  ShowMessage('In button click');
  IdSMTP1.Heloname:='test';
  IdSMTP1.Host:=edtServer.Text;
  IdSMTP1.Username:=edtUsername.Text;
  intPort := 25;
  ShowMessage('Before strtoint');
  TryStrToInt(edtPort.Text, intPort);
  ShowMessage('After strtoint');
  IdSMTP1.Port:= intPort;
  IdSMTP1.Password:=edtPassword.Text;

  if IdSMTP1.Connected=True then IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  IdMessage1.Clear;
  IdMessage1.From.Address := edtFrom.Text;
  IdMessage1.Recipients.Add;
  IdMessage1.Recipients.Items[0].Address := edtTo.Text;
  IdMessage1.Priority := mpHigh;
  IdMessage1.Sender.Address:=edtFrom.Text;
  IdMessage1.Subject := 'Subject';
  IdMessage1.Body.Add('test');
  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
end;

end.
```

Comment: please see the link to full source code... the form dont display and i cant click on "connect" button

Answer (score 1):

Indy is compatible with Android.  This is not an Android problem, it is a configuration problem.

Gmail's Port 465 uses Implicit SSL to encrypt the connection.  Upon connecting to port 465, the server expects your app to initiate an SSL handshake to establish an SSL session before any SMTP data can then be exchanged.

Before connecting, you must attach a `TIdSSLIOHandlerOpenSSL` component to the `TIdSMTP.IOHandler` property, and then set the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` property to `utUseImplicitTLS`.
  Without that, `TIdSMTP` will not send the SSL handshake.  It will simply wait for the server's SMTP greeting, which the server will not send until the SSL session is established first.  A deadlock thus occurs, unless you set the `TIdSMTP.ReadTimeout` property to a non-infinite value so `TIdSMTP.Connect()` can raise an exception when it does not receive the SMTP greeting.

Comment: i change to port 25 and the problem is the same... the form dont show

Comment: When connecting to port 25, a client must issue a `STARTTLS` command after connecting and retreiving the SMTP greetin, before logging in. In `TIdSMTP`, that is accomplished by setting its `UseTLS` property to `utUseExplicitTLS` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Before you deploy to Android device, run on Win32 Platform to check whether OK or not.
Remember to put OpenSSL DLL(libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) on same directory, but it's not OK for Android. 
Here is my code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
with IdMessage1 do
begin
  Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'test@gmail.com';
  From.Address              := 'test@gmail.com';
  From.Name                 := 'Self';
  CCList.EMailAddresses     := '';
  BccList.EMailAddresses    := '';
  Priority                  := mpNormal;
  Subject                   := 'Test Mail Subject';
  Body.Add('Test Mail Body');
end;

with IdSMTP1 do
begin
  Host      := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  Username  := 'xxxxxxx';
  Password  := 'yyyyyyy';
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  Port      := 465;
  UseTLS    := utUseImplicitTLS;

  try
  Connect;
  except
  end;

  if not Connected then
  begin
    Showmessage('Error');
    Exit;
  end;

  try
  Send(IdMessage1);
  finally
  Disconnect;
  end;

 end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for code, but this code works fine on my computer, but Error will be raised in other machines... why is that?